# Does the phrase "which may not seem like much of an [something]" sound natural?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Does the phrase "seem like much of an [something]" sound natural?

For example:

> This might not seem like much of an improvement, but it is.

Comment: That's fine. What particular aspect is giving you pause?

Answer (score 1):

> This might not seem like much of an improvement, but it is.

Yes, that sentence sounds perfectly natural.